# What is the difference between .exrc and .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vi, rc

I know from experience that the ~/.exrc file can be used to configure `vim`.  I also know that the ~/.vimrc file can be used for the same purpose.

However, If I use .exrc to configure `vim`, this leads to problems on systems where `vi` is installed rather than `vim`. Namely, `vim` supports extra features that `vi` does not; and when you try to use them in `vi`, `vi` complains.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between .exrc and .vimrc?
2. If both are present, then are *both* used?
3. Is it bad practice to use the .exrc file to configure `vim`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. .exrc is the configuration file for `vi`, whereas .vimrc is the config file for `vim`
2. No. Vim will use the .vimrc file if present, otherwise the .exrc file if present
3. Yes, unless you only put vi-compatible commands in there

From the Vim help on exrc:

```
 c. Four places are searched for initializations.  The first that exists
is used, the others are ignored.  The $MYVIMRC environment variable is
set to the file that was first found, unless $MYVIMRC was already set
and when using VIMINIT.
-  The environment variable VIMINIT (see also |compatible-default|) (*)
   The value of $VIMINIT is used as an Ex command line.
-  The user vimrc file(s):
        "$HOME/.vimrc"     (for Unix and OS/2) (*)
        "$HOME/.vim/vimrc"     (for Unix and OS/2) (*)
        "s:.vimrc"         (for Amiga) (*)
        "home:.vimrc"      (for Amiga) (*)
        "home:vimfiles:vimrc"  (for Amiga) (*)
        "$VIM/.vimrc"      (for OS/2 and Amiga) (*)
        "$HOME/_vimrc"     (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
        "$HOME/vimfiles/vimrc" (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
        "$VIM/_vimrc"      (for MS-DOS and Win32) (*)
    Note: For Unix, OS/2 and Amiga, when ".vimrc" does not exist,
    "_vimrc" is also tried, in case an MS-DOS compatible file
    system is used.  For MS-DOS and Win32 ".vimrc" is checked
    after "_vimrc", in case long file names are used.
    Note: For MS-DOS and Win32, "$HOME" is checked first.  If no
    "_vimrc" or ".vimrc" is found there, "$VIM" is tried.
    See |$VIM| for when $VIM is not set.
-  The environment variable EXINIT.
   The value of $EXINIT is used as an Ex command line.
-  The user exrc file(s).  Same as for the user vimrc file, but with
   "vimrc" replaced by "exrc".  But only one of ".exrc" and "_exrc" is
   used, depending on the system.  And without the (*)!
```